# How to hide table borders in python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

initial problem was to align image and text to each other
i solved it using table, but i want borders of it to be hidden

i have tried https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/433
but i get:

top.set(qn('w:val'), 'nil')
uri = nsmap[prefix]
KeyError: 'w'

```py
table = document.add_table(0, 2)
row_cells = table.add_row().cells
paragraph = row_cells[0].paragraphs[0]
run = paragraph.add_run()
run.add_picture(image_path, width=Inches(1.5), height=Inches(2.))
table.cell(0, 1).text = text
```

so i want something like this

```
table.Border = None
```